# ANYLOGIC - Cut out data in the log of a specific interval

Tags: simulation, anylogic

Anylogic

Hello everybody, I want to cut out the data from the first 20 days on in the log. Means the simulation should start at t=0 but start collecting the data in the log from day 20 on.

Does anyone knows how this works?

Thanks in advance for your help :-)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do it with the default log (as far as I know), but you can create your own logs at your convenience either by coding it yourself, or generating it with what you read on the section "Creating your own logs":

https://anylogic.help/anylogic/running/logs.html#description

you will need to generate your own code to start logging after a particular amount of time has elapsed.